# Using the browser as a client in python sockets

Tags: python, sockets, client

I need to build a server which can connect to the chrom browser (The browser need to be a client) in TCP protocol, and get from the browser some URL and check if the file it recieved exist in my computer. This code below is work only I use a regular client that I build, and not a browser client.

My question is: How and where do I can send data from the client browser to the server? How do I connect to the browser from the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to connect the browser to the server (your app ) your url should look like this
127.0.0.1:12397 . i am just not sure how are you planning to send the GET request , but now the request will be intercepted by your app ONCE SENT.

Comment: Thanks! Now I connected to the browser, after that, Do you know how can I seperate the file path from the url? When I ask for a file the browsers return a long data And i dont have even a clue for how to seperate the file path.